# C# Object Property to Load Values from List

Tags: c#, object, reflection, casting

I have a class with a property: `public object something { get; set; }`

I obtain a list of values from a method, say `List<string> myList` and I would like to load each value into property `something` without using expando etc.

Basically, I am trying to to:

```
SomePrototypeClass myClass = new SomePrototypeClass();

foreach (string item in myList)
{
myClass.something.Add (item)
}
```

Is this possible? (Reflection or somehow?) Could anyone advise please?

Comment: Why is the property typed `object`?

Comment: Can't you set `something` to `myList` directly? Or what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Just directly set list to your property

     myClass.something = myList;

Comment: The suggestions of setting directly miss the point that it will need to be cast back to `List<string>` each time it is accessed. It is a bad design unless there is a specific reason that isn't clear from the question.

Comment: `myClass.something = new SomeClassThatHasNothingToDo();` is possible. If you have a collection of `SomePrototypeClass` and the property `something` of each items of the collection contains different types, that will really be a pain

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have defined the property as an object, you could set it to a `List<string>` or any other type, directly:

```
myClass.something = myList;
```

You need to cast it back to a `List<string>` or whatever the type of `myList` is to be able to use it as something else than an untyped object though.